# How to get an array from the result of a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I'm not able to get an array from the result of a regex match:

```
var txt = '[Eig2]=>100 [Eig1]=="test"';
var reg = '(\\[)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\\d+)(\\])';
var m = txt.match(new RegExp(reg, ["i"]));
if (m != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        console.log(m[i]);
    }
} else {
    console.log("null");
}
```

What it returns:

```
[Eig2] 
[ 
Eig 
2 
]
```

What I want:

```
[Eig2]
[Eig1]
```

May I have to do it without "new RegExp", but with "/([)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\d+)(])/g" it does not work...

Some ideas?

Regards

Comment: this regex should be better, no? `(\[[A-Z][a-z]+\d+\])`

Comment: `((?:[a-z][a-z]+))` ... the inner non-capturing group seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would simplify the expression:

```
var re = /\[([a-z]{2,}\d+)\]/ig;
```

I've added the `/i` for case insensitive matching and `/g` modifier to match multiple occurrences. Then you call it like this:

```
> txt.match(re);
  ["[Eig2]", "[Eig1]"]
```

To extract the first memory capture:

```
var captures = [];

txt.replace(re, function($0, $1) {
    captures.push($1);
});
```

*Granted, `.replace()` is being abused here*

Then, evaluate captures:

```
> captures
  ["Eigh2", "Eigh1"]
```

**Update**

A somewhat friendlier way to build the array of memory captures:

```
var captures = [], match;

while ((match = re.exec(txt)) !== null) {
    captures.push(match[1]);
});
```

Comment: If I expand the the txt to "[Eig5]=='test' AND [Eig4]>=[Eig3]*2" it just find [Eig5] and [Eig4], but not [Eig3]...any idea?

Comment: `"[Eig5]=='test' AND [Eig4]>=[Eig3]*2".match(re)` gives me `["[Eig5]", "[Eig4]", "[Eig3]"]` @Stev

Answer (score 2):

You should modify

```
var m = txt.match(new RegExp(reg, ["i"]));
```

to

```
var m = txt.match(new RegExp(reg, ["ig"]));
```

Add the `g` flag to your regular expression, which means you want to match all patterns in the string, instead of the first one and its subpatterns.